# How to Clean up Donut Chart?

Tags: r

I need to clean up the donut chart below, by getting rid of the double data labels, and rounding the percents. I would like the final graph to have one data label with a % and no decimal place. Anyone know how I accomplish this?

```
df <- data.frame(
group = cc("DoDEA", "ERAC", "Evaluator", "Project Director", "Project Staff - Finance", 
"Project Staff - Other"),
value = c(3,7, 10, 43, 12, 25))

head(df)
ggdonutchart(df,  label = "group")

ggdonutchart(df, "value",
color = "white",fill = "group",
palette = c("yellow", "steelblue3","slategray3", "dodgerblue4", 
"yellowgreen",  "sienna2") ) +
labs(fill = "") + #THIS DELETS GROUP FROM LEGEND

geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value/sum(value))),
position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`
```

Comment: `scales::percent` has an `accuracy` argument for rounding. If you want to round to the nearest percent, set `accuracy = 1`. For one decimal, use `accuracy = 0.1`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column to your dataframe to create the labels. This code will put the % on a new line. Then add these labels in the `ggdonutchart` function using the `label` argument. The function then has additional arguments to adjust the label position.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("DoDEA", "ERAC", "Evaluator", "Project Director", "Project Staff - Finance", 
             "Project Staff - Other"),
  value = c(3,7, 10, 43, 12, 25))
# create labels
df$label <- paste(df$group,
                  scales::percent(df$value/sum(df$value), accuracy = 1), sep = "\n")

ggdonutchart(df, "value",
             label = "label", # add labels
             color = "white",fill = "group",
             palette = c("yellow", "steelblue3","slategray3", "dodgerblue4", 
                         "yellowgreen",  "sienna2")) +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. The only issue is that now, the label for "Project Staff - Finance" is partially cut off. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Try adjusting `lab.pos` and/or `lab.adjust` to move the labels. You could also use the `lab.font` argument to decrease the label sizes.